# installing ZFTools in zendframework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to install ZFTools for zendframework 2.

I have followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool). I  went to my command line and within the site directory executed the following composer command:

```
composer require zendframework/zftool:dev-master
```

When I then tried to see if it was installing with:

```
zf.php modules
```

I received the following message:

```
$ zf.php modules
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php: line 2: /bin: is a directory
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php: line 3: composer.json: command not found
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php: line 4: composer.json: command not found
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php: line 5: composer.json: command not found
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php: line 6: composer.json: command not found
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php: line 7: composer.json: command not found
```

---

Update:

I did indeed try a composer update but nothing really happened.

I also checked the location of the `zf.php` file; it's located here:

```
C:\Program Files\ZendCli\bin
```

The cygdrive is the command line that I am using.

One thing I did notice however is that composer installed the ZFTOOL under the zendframework library as opposed to the ZF-commons. Was that correct?

---

I tried going to the following directory and then calling the `zf.php` modules:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin
```

I then called :   `$ zf.php modules`

However, I still got the following error message:

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php: line 2: /bin: is a directory
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/classmap_generator.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
```

---

hi again everyone; special thanks to **user1786423**. i got it working. i reinstalled it and placed it in my vendor folder. i can now access it via vendor/ZFTool/zf.php modules.

**quick question though:**  how can i now symlink vendor/ZFTool/zf.php to my project root  so that i only need to type in zf.php rather than the full link

Comment: Are you sure, the path is correct `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php`, because it seems that is not

Comment: First go to your project directory and run these commands. `php composer.phar self-update` and then `php composer.phar update` and then retry

Comment: Actually it seeems as zf.php is run as shell script instead as php. Maybe run it as "php zf.php modules"

Comment: hi everyone, i responded above. i tried all 3 suggestion recommdneded by user1786423, djay and bilal but to no avail. any recommendations would be grately appriciated

Comment: If you go to that directory and call "php" without params, will it work? zendframework direcotry seems ok by looking at composer.json, maybe ZF-commons was older version?

Comment: hi user1786423. i called php from the console line but there was no response

Comment: If there was no error, then php was waiting for input. There are some comments down at http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html stating, that you should cd to your application directory (the one containing vendor/ and module/) and call zf.php from there (like php "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php" modules - quotes might be needed because "program files" contains space, or space might be escapet by \ like 'php /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php modules')

Comment: Hello user1786423. i tried your recommendation but still got the error messages; i have attached my error messages to my main question section. do you have any recommendations.warm regards endy

Comment: If I understand it, you have to use those tools on some zend project - so go to main dir of your ZF(2?) application and then call zf.php by full path - so working directory is your application root. And to be sure it's interpreted correctly, use php to call it - 'php /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php modules', because from your error messages it seems, that it is being interpreted as shell-script instead of php script.

Comment: hi user1786423. i tried calling it and still got this message;$ Could not open input file: /cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php
-bash: Could: command not found. i don't understand the message because the page is definitely in that location

Comment: @andreea115 I don't have cygwin to test, but think problem is, that "Program Files" contains space, 'Program\ Files' would work in linux but maybe not in cygwin, can you try with quotes? 'php "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ZendCli/bin/zf.php" modules' or on pressing TAB, bash in cygwin should try to autocomplete written path and escape it for you.

Comment: hello user1786423. i really appriciate your contiued help on this matter. i tried what you suggest but it did not work. however, i also did this  cd /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/ZendCli/bin/
and i was able to get to the bin folder. so, the address is correct. its the zf.php file that has a problem. i.e i am not able to enter into it. from the bin folder i did an ls and it revealed that the following folders were within the bin folder: classmap_generator.php  zf.bat  zf.php  zf.sh . any ideas why i am not able to enter the file?

Comment: hi user1786423. i got it working. i reinstalled it and placed it in my vendor folder. i can now access it via vendor/ZFTool/zf.php modules. quick question though:  how can i now symlink vendor/ZFTool/zf.php to my project root

Comment: hi, glad to hear, I was out of ideas.. symlink is made by "ln -s path/to/file symlink_name" and it might work under cygwin